# Can I somehow find the wallet id of every trade?

Tags: blockchain

I know we can see the trade flow of BTC trades. Is it somehow possible to associate each trade to a waller? Ie. the initiator of the trade?

Answer (score 4):

Trades on exchanges are not reflected on the Bitcoin blockchain, there are many orders of magnitude more of them than the total number of transactions ever made in the networks history. The only source of information about what exchange transactions have happened is the exchanges themselves, and they expose no identifying information about who made them.